# Is there a way to install fundation 6 with bower

Tags: zurb-foundation, bower

So far I put `"foundation": "^5.5.0"` in my bower.json, but I now want to upgrade to the 6th version and bower don't found it when I replace 5.5.0 by 6.0.0 (and start bower install).

What should I do in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation 6 uses a new package on bower (`foundation-sites`)

Use `bower install foundation-sites --save-dev` to install Foundation 6 and save it to your `bower.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

Because its just released they probably have not updated the bower package list online, For now use it like this (foundation version 6.1.2)
  add to your bower.json

```
    "foundation": "~5.5.3",
    "foundation6": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites.git"
```

then run command `bower install`

Comment: you may remove the 5.5.3 line if you don't want to keep it